Would the discovery of sapient octopus on the coasts of Australia decrease or increase European interest on the continent?
In this alternate timeline, a species of sapient octopus evolved in the shallow coastal waters of Australia (specifically, in the Great Southern Reef.) Due to the isolation of Australia from Afro-Eurasia, non-Australian history remains the same up until the early 1600s, when the first European explorers find Australia. The first of the sapient octopus would probably be encountered by the voyages of Dirk Hartog in 1616, Willem Janszoon in 1618, and by the Tryall in 1622. (Or in 1629 when one shipwrecked Jeronimus Cornelisz got a spear through the face by one of the octopus)
What I am having trouble with is figuring out whether or not the knowledge of this octopus species's existence would trigger greater European exploration of Australia or make it even less than it was in our timeline (In our timeline, there were a couple voyages of exploration spread over the 1600s, and then pretty much nothing until James Cook in the 1770s). On one hand, it could trigger curiosity and a desire to see how the octopus can be exploited, on the other hand, since the octopus would likely be aggressive towards the europeans, it might make europeans lose interest (which was already little) by making trips there more dangerous.
So that is my question, if word spread in Europe about a continent in the south with coasts being inhabited by sapient octopus, would there be more or less exploration of Australia (In the 1600s and early 1700s) than in our history?

Better question: when did the octopi discover us?
Also: What is their tech level? How much can they utilize land and/or control shipping on water?
There is no right answer. The question is entirely storybased. Voting to close.

I say Chaps - Look what we are going to put in the London Museum! Huzzah!

@SRM The question is meant to be about how Europe reacts to the naked knowledge of this new sapient species, the only thing they know is that they are octopus, and they are clearly as smart as humans, anything else should be irrelevant

@KaffeeByte what about the octopi makes it clear that they are as smart as humans? As it stands this question is lacking in information about the octopi themselves

@KaffeeByte You're essentially encompassing the full range of First Contact scenarios. If the octopi are competitors, the reception will be vastly different from if they're sentient but non-aggressive. Is there sexual interest between the two species? Is their voice attractive or repulsive gurgles? All of that will radically change the reception. For any given proposed reaction, I guarantee I can find you a sci-fi story where reaction to new sentient species was the opposite. There is no right answer here.

So... an octopus climbs up onto a 1600s sailing vessel, politely knocks on the captain's door, and says, "Shalom, brudduh. Be you kindly movin' your net? You be takin' all me crabbos." (Said octopus grew up near Jamaica, but admired a Jewish immigrant who fell overboard. Well, before he drowned. Octopi have trouble with the Kiss of Life.) And what would you think the captain would do? (a) Throw his first mate overboard for a lousy practical joke. (b) Cook the convenient octopus. (c) Change his religion. (d) Kill it as the spawn of the devil. You're giving the 17th century a LOT of credit.

FRAME CHALLENGE: It's been pretty much firmly established that Aboriginal Australians in Northern Australia were first contacted by traders from Sulawesi (Indonesia) in the late 16th or very early 17th centuries so say sometime between the 1580's and 1610's. The trade was mostly in trepang (sea cucumbers) which were and still are a highly valued commodity in the Chinese sea food market. As a result this became a well established and long lasting trade route with aboriginals even traveling back to the islands aboard Sulawesi vessels.
Officially the Dutch 'discovered' the far northern reaches of Australia in 1606 but unlike the Sulawesi's there's no record of them ever staying long enough to do more than conduct a cursory examination of the coast before departing. They certainly never reported even rumors of anything remotely of value in Australia by way of 'sea food' products or indeed anything else and completely ignored the Continent afterwards. So if nothing else that indicates they never contacted local Aboriginals in more than the briefest of manners and certainly never learned of the existence of any valuable resources there let alone (in this alternate universe)  your sentient octopuses.
So if there was in fact a species of sentient Octopus living along the coast of Australia and the local aboriginal populations were aware of their existence? It would definitely be the Sulawesi's who were made aware of it first and as a result almost certainly would have interacted with them first (for good or ill) and who would then have spread rumors of their existence out into the wider world. Not Europeans.

The sapient species of octopus specifically lives in the Great Southern Reef, which extends across the coast southern half of Australia, where I believe the Sulawesi didn't reach. While the first couple of voyages might not make the knowledge of it widespread, the Batavia in 1629 might make it widespread. (The accounts of the shipwreck were widely published in 1647, so atleast at that point, the Octopus would become widespread because in this alternate history they played a part in the events of the shipwreck.)

@KaffeeByte the Batavia was wrecked on the Houtman Abrolhos reefs, due to the prevailing ocean currents and shallow water depths these reefs have a warm tropical climate with summer water temperatures reaching above 27C. Temperatures along the northern coasts in summer are about 30C. The range of your octopi could easily extend all the way north.

The question is about European Colonialism.  Being discovered first by an Asian population that does not itself interact with Europe does not really answer the question.

@Nosajimiki  Europeans would interact withe the Octopi. My point however was not that they (the Dutch) would discover their existence directly but rather indirectly as rumors of their existence spread out across the Indonesian Archipelago from Sulawesi. And those rumors/legends WOULD spread fairly quickly to because they would be a big deal! So the end result would be the Dutch sending out expeditions to Australia to actively search for the octopi not discovering them purely by random chance as in the original scenario.

It would dramatically increase human interest. The history of mankind is bloody, and a rival sentient species would not be ignored. If these octopus live mostly underwater, it might be possible that there could be a negotiated coexistence, but only after both sides find out that they cannot simply dominate the other.
SoronelHaetir mentioned the theological aspects, which will matter. "God created mankind in His own image" and "have dominion over the fish in the water" are going to be an explosive combination. But even if that can be overcome, there will be the geopolitical angle. Which might cause one human faction to ally with the octopus against another human faction -- Catholics had no problem dealing with Protestants, and Christians had no problems dealing with Muslims, if that gave a military advantage.

I was sorely tempted to vote to close as too story-based or as not about worldbuilding per the Help Center, which states that the decisions, actions, motivations, etc. of individuals and/or organizations are off-topic because there can be no right answer. Any answer given can be rationalized true or false in your story.
But...
Tales of dragons and krakens and leviathans and mermaids and all sorts of nonsense made their way into everything from taverns and pubs to history books and scientific journal from the early American colonists to somewhere east of Moscow and beyond. Folks were mighty superstitious in the 1600s. You had the Salem Witch Trials in 1692 and Europeans were sporadically burning intelligent women from the 15th to the 18th centuries.
Given the ubiquitous nature of phenomenal belief in western civilization at that time, I think the odds are better than average that nobody would even lift an eyebrow over the claim of an intelligent octopus.
But what if one is captured and returned to Europe?!
Riiiight... (I apologize for the sarcasm. Kinda...) A multi-tentacled creature that likely has equal or superior "arm strength" that can move in both wet and dry environments but prefers salt water, and that has a better-than-average chance of killing some of the crew before they get it into a cage... only to die in transit. But let's say the crew gets it back to Europe alive.
Where it keeps it's big mouth shut. With its dying breath, someone thought they heard it say, "for the brood!"
JBH, You're not taking the question seriously...
Yes I am. People in the 1600s were honking superstitious. The Malleus Maleficarum was still being used to judge women to be witches in the late 1600s and people seriously believed in faeries, trolls, gnomes, leprechauns, and the like.
The Scientific Revolution did, indeed, occur between the 16th and 17th centuries (about the same time as your first-contact scenario), but it took the Age of Enlightenment (17th-18th centuries) to begin (only to begin!) to uncover the eyes of most people, including scientists.
Compared to the fearsome stories of krakens, a tool-using possibly-talking octopus wouldn't even get an honest hearing. By the time enough people became convinced of the truth such that this question would have meaning, the octopus civilization would be battening down the hatches against the we've-been-whaling-for-centuries humans.
And all the octopi would have to do to make the whole rumor go away is to stay away from human ships. Just how sapient are they?
For the record: there's a difference between worldbuilding and storybuilding
Worldbuilding is the infrastructure of the environment. The development of a sapient octopus civilization, for example.
Storybuilding is the "action" that occurs on top of that infrastructure. It can be anything the author wants and is in most cases trivially rationalized in the story. There's a reason the Help Center says we help people build worlds and not tell stories.
There is no scientifically provable facts that answer your question. Although I passionately believe I'm right, there is nothing on Earth I can quote that will prove that I'm right... or that someone with a more Roddenberry-esque outlook on first contact wouldn't be right. There's only the statistics of historical accounts favoring the following ideas...

Historically, colonizers (of any race, ethnicity, or culture) tended to react badly to existing occupiers,

Humanity will believe pretty much anything, and...

It takes a lot to get people away from a sporting event.


But what actually happens is up to you! What do you want to have happen? Do you want Europeans to swarm Australia? Then write your story that way. Do you want them to avoid it like the plague? then write your story that way.
There's no right answer.

There is a right answer. Calamari.

@elemtilas That would be option (b) in the comment I wrote before writing this answer. :-)

Duly noted and appreciated!

I suspect vastly more interest, though not to any benefit of the octopus people.
The Europeans would most likely see these creatures as some kind of devil-spawn and work to eradicate them.

I think it is best look at the mindset of Europeans at the time. One -  they were still conquers at that time, so danger would not sway them at all. Two - they were colectors of artifacts (of which a new culture would have many) and oddities (like sideshow freaks and new creatures like the duck-billed platypus).
So they would be interested in knowing, probably by force, mor about these creature. So now you have to think about what kind of people the Octomen would be. Are the peaceful? Native Americans were so "had to be conquered for their own good." Are they warriors? Then they are monsters that must be controlled. Know that death charges was invented by Leonardo da Vinci (died 1519) but was never used, so they could bomb them.
Last thing is whether or not, most likely not, they could communicate, also what relationship they have the the Aboriginal. They would have myths and legends about the creatures or have personal relationship with them, possibly both.

of course if the European were (as would be likely) the Dutch they'd try to establish influence with the local leadership through trade and logistical support. worked wonders in the East Indies, so why not in Van Diemensland (which in the real world they found pretty barren and useless, only of interest for ships in trouble to get some emergency supplies).

Nothing will change because they don't really stand out as significant
Thylacines, Platypuses, Tasmanian devils, etc. were all completely new creatures to European explorers and were widely considered mythical creatures well into the 1800s.  Not to mention the fact that there were many actual mythical creatures in Australia that many people believed were real like bunyips, yara-ma-yha-who, and muldjewangk.   Infact, an intelligent octopus would not be a strange cryptid at all considering that many people at the time believed in mermaids, fairies, a wide range of sea monsters that were already much closer to home and just as fantastical.
In all likelihood, the stories of intelligent octopuses would either be believed by the same people who believing in the other fantastic creatures that were said to live in Australia, or they would be disbelieved by the same people who disbelieved in all of those same other creatures.
So, while the idea of intelligent octopuses would be an interesting idea to Europeans, they would be no more interesting than a lot of the other creatures explorers reported seeing or hearing about in Australia, but the fact is that Australia was just so far away that none of these rumors garnered much widespread belief in their existence or inspired much research until after Australia was already being colonized.
